# Sending HTML e-mail with Lotusscript agent

Tags: html, email, lotusscript, agent

How to send a e-mail with html content and inline images using lotusscript agent?
GMail removes the inline images to file attachments.
IS it possible to prevent this?

Modification as requested in comments:
I have created a document to be used as mail template. This can be a normal memo in your mail file. In the body I added an image, like company logo, and some text. This memo is sent with lotusscript insted of manual sending button.
The lotusscript agent first remove the body and copy its content to a temporary rtitem. The text is replaced with merge field values. Then a new rich text item is created with the replaced text. The result of the text processing is a removed inline image in gmail.
Hope this information is enough, and this is the reason I think the code is not interesting here.

Comment: Show your code. Otherwise all we can do is make guesses about what you're doing wrong.

Comment: YES, it is possible, but without knowing HOW you add your images, we can not help: Totally agree with Richard...

Comment: Incidentally, I tried sending email manually and the gmail user received the inline images, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

"MIME HTML inline"

look here http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/0/c570f4a6e09a0d7585257333005217e9?OpenDocument

on gmail works.

all best